# Can't write mode PA as PNG

Tags: python

I'm trying to get Images from a pdf file using PyPDF2 library in python. When I uploaded a pdf file which includes 'PA' mode images that it gives a error as cannot write mode PA as PNG.

```
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py", line 1299, in _save
    rawmode, mode = _OUTMODES[mode]
KeyError: 'PA'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 56, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\pdfanalyzer_project\pdfanalyzer\views.py", line 34, in pdfanalyzer
    mydiff.readPdf(request.FILES['chooseFile1'],variable="second",value=1)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\pdfanalyzer_project\pdfanalyzer\controllers\main.py", line 35, in readPdf
    if len(page.images)>0:
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_page.py", line 481, in images
    extension, byte_stream = _xobj_to_image(x_object[obj])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\filters.py", line 617, in _xobj_to_image
    img.save(img_byte_arr, format="PNG")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2431, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py", line 1302, in _save
    raise OSError(msg) from e
OSError: cannot write mode PA as PNG
```

```
for pages in range(len(reader.pages)):  # text okuma süreci başladı
            page = reader.pages[pages]  # pdf içindeki sayfaları okumaya başladık
            if len(page.images)>0:
                for image in page.images:
                    images[value].append(image.name)
```

I tried every way but i didnt find any solution yet.

I try to read Image from pdf and then use them all with cv2.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you'll need to convert the images from `PA` to `RGBA` before saving them, however I don't know PyPDF2 and you haven't shown enough code for me to help fully.

Assuming you have a `PA` mode `PIL Image`, you can use:

```
from PIL import Image
RGBAimage = PAimage.convert('RGBA')
```